# flutter_webview fails showing webpage with three.js render

Tags: flutter, three.js, flutterwebviewplugin

I am using flutter_webview to display URL with some javascript canvas elements.

The URL works fine viewed in any browser, but from Android Studio 3.6 displaying to a Pixel 3 (Android 10) I get a crash approximately 4/5 seconds after running the page - with the following console messages:

---

```
W/Adreno-GSL(10848): <gsl_ldd_control:549>: ioctl fd 61 code 0x400c0907 (IOCTL_KGSL_DEVICE_WAITTIMESTAMP_CTXTID) failed: errno 35 Resource deadlock would occur
W/Adreno-GSL(10848): <log_gpu_snapshot:458>: panel.gpuSnapshotPath is not set.not generating user snapshot
E/chromium(10848): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(17410)] Offscreen context lost via ARB/EXT_robustness. Reset status = GL_UNKNOWN_CONTEXT_RESET_KHR
E/chromium(10848): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(4851)]   GLES2DecoderImpl: Context reset detected after MakeCurrent.
W/Adreno-GSL(10848): <gsl_ldd_control:549>: ioctl fd 61 code 0xc040094a (IOCTL_KGSL_GPU_COMMAND) failed: errno 35 Resource deadlock would occur
W/Adreno-GSL(10848): <log_gpu_snapshot:458>: panel.gpuSnapshotPath is not set.not generating user snapshot
W/Adreno-GSL(10848): <gsl_ldd_control:549>: ioctl fd 61 code 0xc0200933 (IOCTL_KGSL_TIMESTAMP_EVENT) failed: errno 22 Invalid argument
W/Adreno-GSL(10848): <ioctl_kgsl_syncobj_create:4402>: (3e, 25, 46478) fail 22 Invalid argument
W/Adreno-GSL(10848): <gsl_ldd_control:549>: ioctl fd 61 code 0xc0200933 (IOCTL_KGSL_TIMESTAMP_EVENT) failed: errno 22 Invalid argument
W/Adreno-GSL(10848): <ioctl_kgsl_syncobj_create:4402>: (3e, 25, 46478) fail 22 Invalid argument
W/Adreno-GSL(10848): <gsl_ldd_control:549>: ioctl fd 61 code 0xc0200933 (IOCTL_KGSL_TIMESTAMP_EVENT) failed: errno 22 Invalid argument
W/Adreno-GSL(10848): <ioctl_kgsl_syncobj_create:4402>: (3e, 25, 46478) fail 22 Invalid argument
Lost connection to device.
```

---

I've checked the web URL in dev console to see if there is a memory leak. There is none when dislayed via browser.

Does anyone know what could be the cause?

Thanks
CW

Answer (score 1):

I met the same issue. You should check your WebGL code to make sure that you has to init the context before the WebView is visible to the user.